# If the reduced homology group is free of rank what does this say about the actual reduced homology of the give space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If the reduced homology group $\tilde{H}_{i}((\Delta^{n})^{k})$ said to be free of rank $\binom{n}{k+1}$ when $i=k$ what does this mean in practice; what will the actual reduced homology be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you are computing $\tilde{H}_{i}((\Delta^{n})^{k};\mathbb{Z})$, i.e. you are taking coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. To say that this group is free of rank $n \choose k+1$ when $i = k$ means that

$$\tilde{H}_{k}((\Delta^{n})^{k};\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{{n \choose k+1}} \cong \overbrace{\mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}}^{{n \choose k+1} \,\, \mbox{times}}$$

Put another way, this group has no torsion and ${n \choose k+1}$ generators.

---

Example: Let $n = 3, k=2$. Then we are taking a $3$-simplex (tetrahedron) and looking at its $2$-skeleton, which is just the surface of the tetrahedron. This is homeomorphic to a sphere, so its (reduced or otherwise) top-homology $(k=2)$ should be free of rank $1$. And, indeed, ${3 \choose 3}=1$.

Comment: Okay, I htionk I follow but why is is $\binom{n}{k}$ instead of $\binom{n}{k+1}$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks!